# How to create a std::shared_ptr without violating MISRA C++ 2008 Advisory Rule 14-8-2?

Tags: c++, misra

I get this error in PC-Lint (au-misra-cpp.lnt):

> ParameterTest.cpp(40): **error 1963: (Note -- Violates MISRA C++ 2008
>   Advisory Rule 14-8-2, Viable set contains both function and template**:
>   std::shared_ptr::shared_ptr (line
>   499, file C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   11.0\VC\include\memory, module Parameter.cpp), std::shared_ptr::shared_ptr (line
>   485, file C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   11.0\VC\include\memory, module Parameter.cpp)) C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\memory(499): error 830:
>   (Info -- Location cited in prior message)
>           std::shared_ptr info(infoPtr);

On this code:

```
CParameterInfo* infoPtr = new CParameterInfo();
std::shared_ptr<CParameterInfo> info(infoPtr);
```

I've tried to write the code in different ways, but can't find a way that don't give the error above.

Is it possible to make the code MISRA compliant?

Comment: Have you tried `std::shared_ptr<CParameterInfo> info(new CParameterInfo());`? Or even better, `auto info = std::make_shared<CParameterInfo>();`?

Comment: I guess the problem is the fact that `std::shared_ptr` has constructors that are both templates and no templates and you can't do anything about that. If I understand it correctly, IMHO the rule is too strict.

Comment: @CassioNeri your probably right it seems to be a problem in the implementation of shared_ptr, and that it has a template and function with the same signature, making PC-Lint to show the MISRA error. Bur it works when using make_shared so I'll do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd guess that avoiding the constructor might work:

```
auto infoPtr = std::make_shared<CParameterInfo>();
```

This also has the advantage of only doing a single memory allocation, while separate creation of the object and the shared state would need two.